# How do i add a Button in a tablelayout?

Tags: java, android

I have a table that loads products and i need to add the same button in each row in the same column, how do i do that?, loading the button from the xml is not an option :( 
Is the same button with the same function
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a recyclerview wich is very similar to listview except that it inflates a certain xml file to each row

Comment: make the xml file that the recyclerview will inflate a table row and you will make what you want

Comment: The problem is that the table content is not created from the start, so i would have to place the button from the code itself so the button is added every time a new product comes in

Comment: I guess that's what the recyclerview will solve, you can create buttons with it

Comment: but if you haven't try to make a recyclerview before it will take sometime to learn how to do that ,I needed 3 or 4 days to understand it clearly